# Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've just tried to use Android Studio. I've created blank project and tried to create `Activity` which extends `AppCompatActivity`. Unfortunalty Android Studio "says" that it

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

I have  `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+"` in dependency list of my "app" module and rebuilt project several times. However I can only use `ActionBarActivity`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using right build version? is your sdk is up to date?

Comment: @Lingviston you're not using the right version. You should use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0`

Comment: Well there wasn't such version that time.

Comment: But now there is and it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 380, accepted):

### TL;DR:

`File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart`

A little addition to other answers here, for anyone having the same error while using the right lib version and the right class.

When I upgraded to

```
appcompat-v7:22.1.0
```

In which `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated and empty and `AppCompatActivty` is the way to go, due to some glitch in Android Studio, It didn't quite pick up on version change.

i.e. Even though Gradle ran without errors, the IDE itself kept saying
`Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'` (and it also wasn't available through the `Ctrl+N` search)

I looked into the `.idea/libraries` folder and noticed there's no appropriate metafile for the new version of the lib.

So, using the old-reliable **File->Invalidate Caches/Restart** did the trick. Always try this when you feel something is magically wrong with Android Studio.
And then Disable offline mode and sync.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, each time I upgrade the appcompat, I get into lots of problems.

Comment: For me this error popped up when updating to Android Studio 2.0 - Clearing the Cache and Restarting as stated above worked perfectly!

Comment: I have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'` already in my `build.gradle`  ... but still getting the error

Comment: If it didn't work, try this one, worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36641765/3758439

Comment: same in IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: i delete gradle/cache, 4.4 & 2.2.x folders, didn't work, i did invalidate and restart in ide didn't worked, i delete .idea and .gradle folder sided in project files, and restart it, it worked just fine

Comment: for me it only works when I delete the files (.idea/libraries) and re-imported the files

Comment: If above solutions do not work then check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947794/cant-resolve-appcompatactivity/50897316#50897316

Comment: Does not work!  Delete the Libray folder in like in one a few down. It works for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129167/2121630

Comment: For me the following worked : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415300/5597466

Answer (score 170):

If the soft methods via gradle file / "Invalidate caches" and the other IDE tools do not work, use the hard way:

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Navigate in your project to the `.idea` folder
3. Just Rename the `libraries` folder
4. Restart Android Studio. It should now recreate the `libraries` folder and work again.

This worked for me on

```
Android Studio 3.1.2
Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 13, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
```

[Shahbaz Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4670788/shahbaz-ali) confirmed, it works also on

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
```

[moujib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021847/moujib) confirmed, it works on Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Ty for the fix! Also, I would like to know if every user here was using the PC version or iOS version of Android Studio. I have some developer friends who never had any of these issues on iOS. I've had tons of issues on PC. Not sure how many times i've tried to clean/rebuild/invalidate cache...

Comment: Shahbaz Ali and I used the Linux version, moujib only commented that this solution works in 3.2.1

Answer (score 73):

Today (22 April) you can use the new `AppCompatActivity` released with the support libraries v 22.1.0.

Just change your dependency :

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
```

[Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) you can find more info about this new class.

Comment: hmm I'm using a higher version but still encounter the issue
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Answer (score 37):

It is too simple.here are the steps you need to follow

> 1-Exit Android studio.
>
> 2-Go to your project directory.
>
> 3-Something like this in my case( F>Android->YourProjectName->.idea).
>
> 4)-delete libraries folder present in .idea folder.
>
> 5)-restart your android studio.
> and your issue is resolved.

Comment: I would never delete the folder in case something goes terribly wrong. Simply renaming it will suffice. In the worst case scenario, that the libraries folder isn't regenerated, you can go back and restore the "libraries" folder's original name. After everything is known to work, you can then go back and delete the folder you renamed. If your studio is corrupted, it may not regenerate folders - always take caution when deleting files.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: After deleting the library folder, come back to android studio. "Do Sync Project with Gradle files"

Answer (score 28):

I got it fixed by Going to `build.gradle` file and in dependencies the `appcompat` one, something like compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.X'`

Changed it to compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.+'`

Then click on Sync. All the red squiggly lines should go if everything else in your code is correct.

Comment: +1, OMG this worked for me. :)  BTW the `+` sign is for _Hey Gradle if any new version of the same release is availible use is for yourself_ :) . I was using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` now this did a trick: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.+` Though AS giving me warning: **Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.+)**

Answer (score 15):

Check for typos too, i wasted my whole day looking for solutions when i had actually typed AppCompactActivity instead of AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 15):

**Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity Issue.**

*Do the Simple Step to resolve the problem.*

i)   Exit the Android studio.

ii)  Go to your project directory.

iii) Find the **.idea** folder in your project directory.

iv)  Delete **.idea** folder.

v)   Restart your android studio.

vi)  The Issue Will be resolved.

Comment: If you go inside the .idea folder and rename the "libraries" folder to something different, the trick works as well. If something goes terribly wrong, you only have to go back and rename the libraries folder back to it's original name and try something else, rather than try to restore the entire .idea folder.

Answer (score 15):

When you add AndroidX support in Gradle.properties file e.g.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If you are using Gradle version greater than 3.2, the conventional Appcompat dependancy e.g.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

wont work.
Replace this dependancy with:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Moreover, change the AppCompatActivity import in your class file from this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

to this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Done

Comment: Best explaination. it worked

Answer (score 13):

I got the `Cannot resolve symbol` error for AppCompatActivity and many other classes & methods after updating Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3, updating Android Gradle plugin to 2.3.0, and updating Gradle to 3.3.

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` did not resolve the issue.

`Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle` showed `Use local gradle distribution` selected with Gradle home: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.14.1 and **a warning displayed saying the gradle location was incorrect**.

Resolved issue by selecting `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`.
Probably just pointing to the new local distribution location would also work.

Answer (score 10):

Try this. In Android Studio, after putting the dependency in build.gradle.
Go to Build --> Clean Project.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Thats really insane, i tried everything, synced with Gradle files, invalidated and restarted android studio. Still the problem persisted. Last resort was deleting **.idea/libraries** folder and it worked as charm.

Answer (score 6):

You can use new AppCompatActivity appcompat-v7:22.1.+
Just add this to your gradle:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue resolved when i updated the appcompact v7 to latest..

**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'**

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 6):

So my collegue pushed their `local.properties` which broke everything. I copied my sdk path from another app and did:

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this same problem with Android SDK 23, while developing on a Mac OS X Yosemite Machine. It turned out that I did not have Java SDK 7.

Once I installed Java SDK 7 and pointed the SDK from with the Android Studio to the new SDK, everything worked for me.

Here are the steps that I followed:

1) Shutdown Android SDK

2) Install Java SDK for Mac OS X from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

3) Start the Android SDK and point the SDK for this project to the new 1.7 Java SDK by going to File -> Project Structure -> JDK Location

4) Restart Android Studio

Hope this help

Answer (score 4):

none of below solved my issue

- Restart Android
- File >> Synch Project with Gradle Files
- Build >> Clean Project
- Build >> Rebuild Project
- File >> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Instead, I solved it by updating the version of appcompat & design dependencies to the recent version 
To do so: go to **build.grade (Module:app)** >> dependencies section and then hit **ALT + ENTER**  on both appcompat & design dependencies then select the shown version in my case it's 24.2.1 as shown in the picture 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remember to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or add the import.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Answer (score 3):

I updated my Gradle 2.3.3 to 4.4 and got an error on AppCompatActivity and also Cardview.  I tried with clean project and rebuild project. It won't work, then I go to **Project Folder** -> **.idea** -> create backup of **libraries** folder and remove it -> then **Rebuild Project** that solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Lets get going step by step: first clean project by using

Build->Clean

if this doesn't helps then use your second step

File>Invalidate Caches/Restart...

But the real problem begins when all the above options doesn't works so use your ultimate solution is to close project and go to project location directory and delete

.idea

You can open your project now again.

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to the latest support library, I had to upgrade to the latest Android studio (beta) version and gradle version before the IDE recognized AppCompatActivity again (invalidating caches and restart did not do the trick)

Answer (score 2):

Add this dependency in project build .gradle.

Follow the example below.

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I use `:22.0.0` and cannot find `AppCompatActivity` class. I have to set it at least to `22.1.0`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Easist Way

- Open app level `build.gradle` and remove **appcompact-v7** dependency & Sync.
- Add dependency again & Sync.

Error gone!

#### Before

[image: before]

#### After

[image: after]

Answer (score 2):

I solved it adding:

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

in the "import" zone of the main .java file. It worked for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You Have to just Do some change in your Gradle App File by adding some dependency

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX:YY:ZZ"

while XX:YY:ZZ is the version code that you are using in your gradle file, otherwise if you set this version lower or higher than that you are using , then your app will face some problems like it will crash sometimes

Answer (score 1):

i just update my android studio from 2.3.2 to 3.1.2 version. and this error occurs.

i clean project, rebuild project, invalidate cache/restart but nothing works.

i resolve this error by updating appcompat library from

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

to

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

in app build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

If Invalidating caches not helps, just close the project then re-open it. Steps:

- File > Close Project
- Remove the project out of the starting project list
- Close Android Studio
- Open Android Studio
- Open existed Project with this project

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of one the following reasons:

1. You do not have the SDK API installed (this was my problem)
2. Your project/Android Studio doesn’t know where the needed files are
3. Your project references an outdated compile version that does not support AppCompatActivity
4. There is a typo

Possible solutions:

1. Check your .gradle file to make sure you’re not referencing an outdated version. AppCompatActivity was added in version 25.1.0 and belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1, so do not use any version earlier than this. In your build.gradle (Module: app) file you should have the dependency listed:

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
   }

   You may be using a different version, but just make sure you have listed the 
   dependency.
2. Open the SDK manager and download every API 7 or newer. If you were missing the needed API it will fix that issue, and downloading all the newer API’s can save you some hassle later on as well.
3. Check for typos in your import statement. Make sure it doesn’t say “AppCompactActivity” instead of “AppCompatActivity”.
4. Resync your project (File >Sync project with Gradle files)
5. Rebuild your project (Build >rebuild)
6. Clean your project (Build >clean project)
7. Close and restart Android Studio
8. Update Android Studio
9. Regenerate your libraries folder – In Android Studio, view your files in project view. Find the folder YourProjectName >.idea >libraries. Rename the folder to “libraries_delete_me”. Close and reopen Android Studio. Open your project again and the libraries folder should be regenerated with all of the files; you can now delete the “libraries_delete_me” folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue resolved when I updated the Gradle build version. Don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how did i solved this problem in eclipse.
Download zip file from this link.https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat then extract this file,open project, in lib folder you will see one jar file named "android-support-v7-appcompat" , add this jar file into your project. Thats it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This can might be in the version difference in the app level gradle check it once and then re-build

Answer (score 0):

For me worked no one of the solutions. But I found out that all the libraries of the support libraries were missing at my external libraries. And in other projects the AppCompatActivity was resolved without problems.

For me it worked to create a new project and copy all the stuff of the old src folder into the new project.

I don't know exact why, but if nothing works, it could be the last possibility. Just if someone has the same trouble as me.

Answer (score 0):

By trying soft ways it wont works, use the hard way:
Exit Current Android Studio Screen and goto your project to the .idea folder Rename the libraries->lib_pre folder.

Restart Android Studio.It will now recreate the libraries folder and work again Smoothly.
Android Studio 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This is the lifesaver code I found somewhere(sorry don't remember the origin). Add it to build.gradle (Module:app). You can replace the version to the relevant.

```
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details -
        def requested = details.requested

 if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {

            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        } else if (requested.group == "com.google.android.gms") {
            details.useVersion '15.0.0'
        } else if (requested.group == "com.google.firebase") {
            details.useVersion '15.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else has failed, make sure you have added the import statement. I had removed it as it was showing error and forgot to add it back and was trying everything else to fix:

> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 0):

After trying literally every solution, I realised that the project I had been working on was previously using the latest Android Studio which was 3.2 at the time and the current pc I was using was running 2.2 after **updating android studio** this seemed to fix the issue completely for me.

Solution: **Android Studio -> Check For Updates and then install latest build**

Answer (score 0):

The error came when i added firebase to the project with all dependencies updated to latest version on API 28 although my google services were using 4.1.0 version.

I removed the error, when i updated it to 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, adding below `dependencyResolutionManagement` in `settings.gradle` solved the problem.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Note: I was migrating the old android project to AndroidX. After following all mandatory steps ended at this issue `Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'`. After trying all the other solutions mentioned here issue was not resolved. When checked with `settings.gradle` and adding the above code solved the issue.

Comment: it is already there

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle version to solve this issue

**Goto your project level build.gradle**

If you are using an old gradle version, upgrade to latest

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

change distributionUrl to  latest version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
```