# Can not add two buttons in action bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am very new. I want to show two button and change their icons but I failed.
I don't understand the problem.

[You can also use "always" to declare that an item always appear as an action button.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)  I read it and used always but it didn' work.

menu_mainxml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_setting"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_about"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

MainActivityjava:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MenuItem item1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    item1= menu.findItem(R.id.action_about);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

     //some code
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_about) {

    //some code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

My result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in your activity:

```
private MenuItem item1;



     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            item1= menu.findItem(R.id.action_about);

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I got same result again

Comment: add tools:context=".YourActivityName" in your menu tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Activity, try using AppCompatActivity.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**menu_main**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_setting"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_about"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: @ffttyy On what? One of the icons?

Comment: on 'AppCompatActivity'. It written by red color

Comment: @ffttyy Try replacing **AppCompatActivity** with **ActionBarActivity** and replace **import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;** with **import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;**

Comment: @ffttyy It may have something to do with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199891/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity

Answer (score 0):

you should use below code and remove myapp prefrex instead used android like below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true" />

</menu>
```