# Cannot Resolve Symbol AppCompatActivity, Cannot Resolve Symbol ContextCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Everything works fine, but in Android Studio showing below errors
[image]

the code runs but unable to get suggestions for functions, class etc.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried invalidate catch and restart ?

Comment: yup, restarted machine also

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding project

Comment: Rebuild and clean project , make sure there is no issues in gradle and classes also , xml also

Comment: already tried, but not working

Comment: what is the version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` ?

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: delete files in build and app/build manually and   invalidate  cache in android studio

Comment: how manually I could invalidate cache

Comment: you can't invalidate cache manually it done in files ->invalidate caches /restart , but you delete build folder by any file explorer

Comment: its not working, tried many times

Comment: First, remove all red highlighted imports and again import it manually by using suggestions of Android Studio.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question, It doesn't show me any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same exact issue as you... upgraded to 3.1.2/3 and turned into a mess.

Try the following approach of deleting the libraries folder from .idea!

[Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199891/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity/50129167#50129167)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but I need to do it for my all projects