# With API 28 and "androidx.appcompat" library project says "AppCompatActivity" symbol not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat, androidx

I updated my build and target version to 28 (Pie) and replaced the relevant dependencies. Now my project says Symbol not found on `AppCompatActivity`. I have tried to

- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- Invalidate Caches / Restart

But the result is the same. Moreover when I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after extends keyword in activity class there is no `"AppCompatActivity` suggestion. I tried to investigate if its present in `libraries` folder, it's present there.

[image]

Now, what should I do to make it work? If there is any variation/alternative with `androidx` libs please let me know. Here is my complete `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.invogen.messagingapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    // Libs for newer API 28
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Libs for Firebase Functionality
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

    // Lib for Firebase UI Elements
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'

    // Libs for QR Code
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'

    // Lib for Circle Image View (Profile Image)
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    // Lib for Loading Images
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //Lib for Cropping Images
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Some other posts suggest adding the below two parameters in `Manifest` file

```
android:appComponentFactory="anystrings be placeholder"
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

But with these two lines project sync with multiple error and Android Studio says

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

If I have to add more detail to the question please let me know.

Comment: It worked for me, just make sure you have selected add unabmigious import on fly option from settings.

Comment: @KaranMer, Yeah I know that and has already checked unambiguous import checkbox but don't know why android studio did not worked for me.

Comment: It might be problem with particular version of android studio. not sure though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Now you can easily migrate your project to `androidx`, Just click `Refactor => Migrate to Androidx` from menubar.
[image]

**Previously I did as follow.**
With `Clean and build` and `Rebuild project` android studio did not clean the unused imports like imports from `android.support.v7` so I removed them all manually from all activities. Now android studio suggests `AppCompatActivity` from the correct library `androidx.appcompat`.

Hope so it will help someone.

Comment: Note, this didn't fix all the occurrences in our application codebase. I had to manually build and track down all the remaining issues. Not sure why but just be aware it's not a silver bullet and there will likely be some manual intervention required.

Answer (score 39):

you should replace the target class.

eg.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

replace to :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: This solution fixes the issue, but does require the aforementioned gradle update: `api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`.  For those on *Day-1* of AndroidX like myself - I didn't realize it is a critical detail listed in the original question, that is part of the solution.  Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936857/2162226

Answer (score 5):

Add Below lines in your gradle Properties:

***android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true***

This will upgrade your project into Android X.