# BottomNavigationView inflate error after migrating to androidx

Tags: android, androidx, appcompatactivity

When I try to launch my app, my Mainactivity throws this error in the oncreate() method at  **"setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"**   :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject/com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject.Fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

This Error appeared after migrating to **androidx**, after further inspection I noticed that the import statements in the Bottomnavigationview class were outdated (no androidx format, but old format). The Bottomnavigationview class file is read only, so I can't edit it.

*gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sanchez.worldgramproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/Yfek0YCH

Is there any way to change all import statements to fit the new androidx format? and how can I do this for all the other classes aswell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
}
```

and use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: Here's a list of all package names to update, for shifting over to AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @GeneBo [material.io](https://material.io/design/) is not directly related to `androidx` anymore; even if it is the successor of package `android.support.design`, meanwhile it has it's own name-space.

Comment: I am on day 2 being aware of these updates (AndroidX, etc), as I had been working from earlier API versions.  Trying to make a successful upgrade for an established codebase (written over the last 1-2 years) to AndroidX seemed relevant to what you share in your post. For me, it was a step in getting the *"upgrade overhaul"* to work. Not sure, as this is new territory for me, but it seems like it's at least in a related context.  I added the note here in case there are other folks finding AndroidX for the first time and trying to get existing code to work.  Thanks for the insight