# Run C++ code in Java Android app using JavaCPP

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, javac, javacpp

I a beginner when it comes to development for Android and I am trying to understand [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp). I want to execute a `C++` function from `Java` inside an `Android` application. In my example I just use a simple `TextView` widget that prints what I receive from `C++`.
Following the documentation, inside the app's `build.gradle` I have included my `javacpp` library dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.4'
}
```

in order to use it in my app. I am testing inside a *Native C++* Android Studio template project.

I have uploaded the full project on GitHub for reference: https://github.com/jacobkrieg10/javacppnewexample

And also, down are the relevant files in the project that I think need attention:

**NativeLibrary.java**:

```
package com.example.javacplusplus;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="NativeLibrary.h")
@Namespace("NativeLibrary")
public class NativeLibrary {
    public static class NativeClass extends Pointer {
        static { Loader.load(); }
        public NativeClass() { allocate(); }
        private native void allocate();

        // to call the getter and setter functions
        public native @StdString String get_property();
        public native void set_property(String property);

        // to access the member variable directly
        public native @StdString String property();
        public native void property(String property);
    }
}
```

**NativeLibrary.h**:

```
#ifndef NATIVELIBRARY_H
#define NATIVELIBRARY_H

#include <string>

namespace NativeLibrary {
    class NativeClass {
    public:
        const std::string& get_property();
        void set_property(const std::string& property);
        std::string property;
    };
}

#endif // NATIVELIBRARY_H
```

**NativeLibrary.cpp**:

```
#include "NativeLibrary.h"

namespace NativeLibrary {

const std::string& NativeClass::get_property() { return property; }
void NativeClass::set_property(const std::string& property) { this->property = property; }

} // namespace NativeLibrary
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(
        native-lib

        SHARED

        NativeLibrary.cpp
        native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
        log-lib

        log)

target_link_libraries(
        native-lib

        ${log-lib})
```

Note that *native-lib.cpp* is just the C++ file used in the template, I am ignoring it for now.

**build.gradle** *(corresponding to the `app` module)*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.javacplusplus"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.javacplusplus;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Pointer objects allocated in Java get deallocated once they become unreachable,
        // but C++ destructors can still be called in a timely fashion with Pointer.deallocate()
        NativeLibrary.NativeClass l = new NativeLibrary.NativeClass();
        l.set_property("Hello World!");

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(l.property());
//        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

The application builds fine, but it crashes at runtime inside `NativeLibrary.NativeClass l = new NativeLibrary.NativeClass();`, with the message `couldn't find "libjniNativeLibrary.so"` this is my crash log:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-11-16 00:57:38.557 13506-13506/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.javacppapp, PID: 13506
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.javacppapp-8V-wRac6X4RLpYvvYEmtGQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjniNativeLibrary.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1683)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1300)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1123)
        at com.example.javacppapp.NativeLibrary$NativeClass.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:10)
        at com.example.javacppapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2020-11-16 00:57:38.557 13506-13506/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Note that the example is working when I execute it on desktop x64. So, e.g., using the following `NativeLibrary.java` file:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="NativeLibrary.h")
@Namespace("NativeLibrary")
public class NativeLibrary {
    public static class NativeClass extends Pointer {
        static { Loader.load(); }
        public NativeClass() { allocate(); }
        private native void allocate();

        // to call the getter and setter functions 
        public native @StdString String get_property();
        public native void set_property(String property);

        // to access the member variable directly
        public native @StdString String property();
        public native void property(String property);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pointer objects allocated in Java get deallocated once they become unreachable,
        // but C++ destructors can still be called in a timely fashion with Pointer.deallocate()
        NativeClass l = new NativeClass();
        l.set_property("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(l.property());
    }
}
```

the output of

```
$ javac -cp javacpp.jar NativeLibrary.java
$ java -jar javacpp.jar NativeLibrary
$ java -cp javacpp.jar NativeLibrary
$ Hello World!
```

is `Hello World!` so it works fine. But I don't know why it doesn't work inside an Android app.

Can anybody help me with this? Does anybody know why it couldn't find `libjniNativeLibrary.so`? Is there something I need to add in order to complete the setup? Perhaps `libjniNativeLibrary.so` needs to be generated somehow?

### EDIT 1:

I have added the `Build Plugin` and the `Platform Plugin` to the project's `build.gradle` file; this is how it looks like now:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-build' version "$javacppVersion"
    id 'org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-platform' version "$javacppVersion"
}

ext {
    javacppPlatform = 'android-arm64' // or any other platform, defaults to Loader.getPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    api "org.bytedeco:javacpp:$javacppVersion"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

// Note: Had to comment this as I was getting the error > Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.
//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}

tasks.withType(org.bytedeco.gradle.javacpp.BuildTask) {
    // set here default values for all build tasks below, typically just includePath and linkPath,
    // but also properties to set the path to the NDK and its compiler in the case of Android
}

javacppBuildCommand {
    // typically set here the buildCommand to the script that fills up includePath and linkPath
}

javacppBuildParser {
    // typically set here the classOrPackageNames to class names implementing InfoMap
}

javacppBuildCompiler {
    // typically set here boolean flags like copyLibs
}
```

The project synchronizes without errors but when I run it, I get:

```
> Task :javacppBuildParser FAILED
Execution failed for task ':javacppBuildParser'.
> app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/myjavacppapp/BuildConfig (wrong name: com/example/myjavacppapp/BuildConfig)
```

Is it beacause I didn't write anything inside `javacppBuildCommand`, `javacppBuildParser` and `javacppBuildParser`?
I know this is a basic question, but does anyone know what exactly I should write inside those blocks? I'm quite new to this and I don't know exactly where to look for this information.

### EDIT 2:

After trying the solution presented in **EDIT 1**, above, I came across [A guide on how to run Javacpp on Android studio together with gradle](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/wiki/Gradle) wiki page and as instructed there I have added this to my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.doLast {
            println 'javacpp ' + variant.name
            javaexec {
                main 'org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Builder'
                classpath '/home/jacob/Work/other/sandbox/java/javacpp3/app/libs/javacpp.jar'
                args '-cp', variant.javaCompiler.destinationDir,
                        '-properties', 'android-arm',
                        '-Dplatform.root=/home/jacob/.android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462',
                        '-Dplatform.compiler=/home/jacob/.android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++',
                        '-Dplatform.includepath=/home/jacob/.android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include:src/main/cpp',
                        '-Dplatform.linkpath=/home/jacob/.android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a',
                        '-d', 'libs/armeabi'
            }
            println 'javacpp done'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}
```

The gradle sync runs ok but when I build the project I get:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
javacpp debug
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.UserClassLoader.findClass(UserClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addClass(ClassScanner.java:61)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingFile(ClassScanner.java:75)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.java:87)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.java:85)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.java:85)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addMatchingDir(ClassScanner.java:85)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.ClassScanner.addPackage(ClassScanner.java:99)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Builder.classesOrPackages(Builder.java:672)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Builder.main(Builder.java:962)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.UserClassLoader.findClass(UserClassLoader.java:72)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jacob/Work/other/sandbox/java/javacpp3/app/build.gradle' line: 48

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Process 'command '/home/jacob/.android/studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling the JavaCPP Builder? Something like this: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-build-plugin

Comment: @SamuelAudet Thank you very much for the answer and suggestions! I have tried adding the `build plugin` and the `platform plugin`, could you please check my *EDIT 1* updates to the question above? Could you please be kind to help me understand why exactly does it fail and what should I put inside the `javacppBuildCommand`, `javacppBuildParser` and `javacppBuildParser`. I know this is probably something basic, but I'm just starting to understand Gradle and I'm not sure where to look for this specific info.
Thank you very much!

Comment: There is a working example here: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/tree/master/samples/zlib

Comment: BTW, here is someone who seems to have it working without any problems: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/issues/5 Please try to contact them see if they would be ready to release the code! Thanks

Comment: If you're willing to spend money for this, I'd be happy to create a sample project for you: https://xscode.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/harshsaver/findfilebycontent
I am successfully calling CPP functions from Java and transferring data between them as well and then showing the results on the app's UI.

(Check the native-lib.cpp file in the cpp folder and the SearchAct.java  from the main res folder)

Comment: @HarshSavergaonkar Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I am aware of the mechanisms that JNI provides for bridging C++ and Java and I know how to use them; however they don't provide the easability that JavaCPP provides. Using JavaCPP you can have C++ interfaces that are directly implemented in Java, which is of great use when it comes to maintainability e.g. I am looking for a simple Android sample in which I can implement a C++ virtual function in Java.

Comment: Perhaps you should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199891/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted a complete working example here:
https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/tree/master/gradle-javacpp-android

For reference, we can reproduce this project with these steps by:

1. Following the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code ,
2. Adding something like below to the `app/build.gradle` file (after applying in the usual manner the `org.bytedeco.gradle-javacpp-build` plugin), and

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantName = variant.name.capitalize() // either "Debug" or "Release"
    def javaCompile = project.tasks.getByName("compile${variantName}JavaWithJavac")
    def generateJson = project.tasks.getByName("generateJsonModel$variantName")

    // Compiles NativeLibraryConfig.java
    task "javacppCompileJava$variantName"(type: JavaCompile) {
        include 'com/example/myapplication/NativeLibraryConfig.java'
        source = javaCompile.source
        classpath = javaCompile.classpath
        destinationDir = javaCompile.destinationDir
    }

    // Parses NativeLibrary.h and outputs NativeLibrary.java
    task "javacppBuildParser$variantName"(type: org.bytedeco.gradle.javacpp.BuildTask) {
        dependsOn "javacppCompileJava$variantName"
        classPath = [javaCompile.destinationDir]
        includePath =  ["$projectDir/src/main/cpp/"]
        classOrPackageNames = ['com.example.myapplication.NativeLibraryConfig']
        outputDirectory = file("$projectDir/src/main/java/")
    }

    // Compiles NativeLibrary.java and everything else
    javaCompile.dependsOn "javacppBuildParser$variantName"

    // Generates jnijavacpp.cpp and jniNativeLibrary.cpp
    task "javacppBuildCompiler$variantName"(type: org.bytedeco.gradle.javacpp.BuildTask) {
        dependsOn javaCompile
        classPath = [javaCompile.destinationDir]
        classOrPackageNames = ['com.example.myapplication.NativeLibrary']
        compile = false
        deleteJniFiles = false
        outputDirectory = file("$projectDir/src/main/cpp/")
    }

    // Picks up the C++ files listed in CMakeLists.txt
    generateJson.dependsOn "javacppBuildCompiler$variantName"
}
```

3. Updating the `CMakeLists.txt` file to include the generated `.cpp` files.